# jquery width() with newly generated element

Tags: jquery, width

When I use the following :

```
div = '<div class="tag-tooltip" id="tooltip_view_1">First item</div>';
$('#products').append(div);

var tooltip_width = $('#tooltip_view_1').width(); 
var tooltip_height = $('#tooltip_view_1').height();
```

The **tooltip_height** gives a correct value, while **tooltip_width** returns 0. Any idea why is this happening and what should I do to get the width of the newly created element?

Comment: Is width set in any container element?

Comment: There is - the parent of this one

Comment: It's working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/EQqHZ/

Comment: works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Dtx9v/1/ - please include css as well.

Comment: Ok- it appears that text-indent:-9999em was what was causing a problem.

Comment: For @user398341: I always wonder why people use these numeric user names on SO.  We have no chance of remembering who you are when our paths next cross.  The user name doesn't have to be real, but at least make it something we'd have a chance to remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to say I've solved the problem - it appears css property : text-indent is also affecting visibility of the element. I had it set to the negative value and once removed this property altogether - everything started working fine.